# Coq simpl for Program Fixpoint

Tags: coq, theorem-proving, totality

is there anything like the tactic `simpl` for `Program Fixpoint`s?

In particular, how can one proof the following trivial statement?

```
Program Fixpoint bla (n:nat) {measure n} :=
match n with
| 0 => 0
| S n' => S (bla n')
end.

Lemma obvious: forall n, bla n = n. 
induction n. reflexivity.
(* I'm stuck here. For a normal fixpoint, I could for instance use 
simpl. rewrite IHn. reflexivity. But here, I couldn't find a tactic 
transforming bla (S n) to S (bla n).*)
```

Obviously, there is no `Program Fixpoint` necessary for this toy example, but I'm facing the same problem in a more complicated setting where I need to prove termination of the `Program Fixpoint` manually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not used to using `Program` so there's probably a better solution but this is what I came up with by unfolding `bla`, seeing that it was internally defined using `Fix_sub` and looking at the theorems about that function by using `SearchAbout Fix_sub`.

```
Lemma obvious: forall n, bla n = n.
Proof.
intro n ; induction n.
 reflexivity.
 unfold bla ; rewrite fix_sub_eq ; simpl ; fold (bla n).
 rewrite IHn ; reflexivity.

(* This can probably be automated using Ltac *)
 intros x f g Heq.
  destruct x.
  reflexivity.
  f_equal ; apply Heq.
Qed.
```

In your real-life example, you'll probably want to introduce reduction lemmas so that you don't have to do the same work every time. E.g.:

```
Lemma blaS_red : forall n, bla (S n) = S (bla n).
Proof.
intro n.
 unfold bla ; rewrite fix_sub_eq ; simpl ; fold (bla n).
 reflexivity.

(* This can probably be automated using Ltac *)
 intros x f g Heq.
  destruct x.
  reflexivity.
  f_equal ; apply Heq.
Qed.
```

This way, next time you have a `bla (S _)`, you can simply `rewrite blaS_red`.

Comment: In the same idea, you can state the equation lemma for `bla`: `forall n, bla n = match n with | 0 => 0 | S n' => S (bla n') end.`

Comment: Is that really the best answer? Doesn’t that make `Program Fixpoint` relatively tedious for large functions, when you have to manually write a reduction lemma?

Comment: More recent plugins like `Equations` generate reduction lemmas for you.