# Coq Program Fixpoint vs equations as far as best way to get reduction lemmas?

Tags: coq, edit-distance, proof-of-correctness

I am trying to prove that particular implementations of how to calculate the edit distance between two strings are correct and yield identical results. I went with the most natural way to define edit distance recursively as a single function (see below). This caused coq to complain that it couldn't determine the decreasing argument. After some searching, it seems that using the Program Fixpoint mechanism and providing a measure function is one way around this problem. However, this led to the next problem that the tactic simpl no longer works as expected. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36329256/coq-simpl-for-program-fixpoint) which has a similar problem, but I am getting stuck because I don't understand the role the Fix_sub function is playing in the code generated by coq for my edit distance function which looks more complicated than in the simple example in the previous question.

Questions:

1. For a function like edit distance, could the Equations package be easier to use than Program Fixpoint (get reduction lemmas automatically)? The previous question on this front is from 2016, so I am curious if the best practices on this front have evolved since then.
2. I came across this coq [program](http://why.lri.fr/examples/edit-distance/words.html) involving edit_distance that using an inductively defined prop instead of a function. Maybe this is me still trying to wrap my head around the Curry-Howard Correspondence, but why is Coq willing to accept the inductive proposition definition for edit_distance without termination/measure complaints but not the function driven approach? Does this mean there is an angle using a creatively defined inductive type that could be passed to edit_distance that contains both strings that wrapped as a pair and a number and process on that coq would more easily accept as structural recursion?

Is there an easier way using Program Fixpoint to get reductions?

```
Fixpoint min_helper (best :nat) (l : list nat) : nat :=
match l with
  | nil => best
  | h::t => if h<?best then min_helper h t else min_helper best t
end.


Program Fixpoint edit_distance (s1 s2 : string) {measure (length s1+ length s2)} : nat :=
match s1, s2 with 
    | EmptyString , EmptyString => O
    | String char rest , EmptyString => length s1
    | EmptyString , String char rest => length s2
    | String char1 rest1 , String char2 rest2  =>  
                let choices : list nat :=  S ( edit_distance rest1 s2) :: S (edit_distance s1 rest2) :: nil   in 
                if (Ascii.eqb char1 char2) 
                        then  min_helper (edit_distance rest1 rest2 ) choices
                        else min_helper (S (edit_distance rest1 rest2)) choices
end.
Next Obligation.
intros. simpl. rewrite <- plus_n_Sm.    apply Lt.le_lt_n_Sm. reflexivity. Qed.
Next Obligation.
simpl. rewrite <- plus_n_Sm.    apply Lt.le_lt_n_Sm. apply PeanoNat.Nat.le_succ_diag_r. Qed.
Next Obligation. 
simpl. rewrite <- plus_n_Sm.    apply Lt.le_lt_n_Sm. apply PeanoNat.Nat.le_succ_diag_r. Qed.

Theorem simpl_edit : forall (s1 s2: string), edit_distance s1 s2  = match s1, s2 with 
    | EmptyString , EmptyString => O
    | String char rest , EmptyString => length s1
    | EmptyString , String char rest => length s2
    | String char1 rest1 , String char2 rest2  =>  
                let choices : list nat :=  S ( edit_distance rest1 s2) :: S (edit_distance s1 rest2) :: nil   in 
                if (Ascii.eqb char1 char2) 
                        then  min_helper (edit_distance rest1 rest2 ) choices
                        else min_helper (S (edit_distance rest1 rest2)) choices
end.
Proof. intros.  induction s1.
  -  induction s2.
  -- reflexivity. 
  --  reflexivity. 
  -  induction s2. 
  --  reflexivity. 
  --  remember (a =? a0)%char as test. destruct test. 
  ---  (*Stuck??? Normally I would unfold edit_distance but the definition coq creates after unfold edit_distance ; unfold edit_distance_func is hard for me to reason about*)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instead use `Function`, which comes with Coq and produces a reduction lemma for you (this will actually also generate a graph as `Inductive R_edit_distance` in the vein of the alternative development you mention, but here it's quite gnarly—that might be because of my edits for concision)

```
Require Import String.
Require Import List.
Require Import PeanoNat.
Import ListNotations.
Require Import FunInd.
Require Recdef.

Fixpoint min_helper (best : nat) (l : list nat) : nat :=
  match l with
  | [] => best
  | h :: t => if h <? best then min_helper h t else min_helper best t
  end.

Function edit_distance
  (ss : string * string) (* unfortunately, Function only supports one decreasing argument *)
  {measure (fun '(s1, s2) => String.length s1 + String.length s2) ss} : nat :=
  match ss with 
  | (String char1 rest1 as s1, String char2 rest2 as s2)  =>
    let choices := [S (edit_distance (rest1, s2)); S (edit_distance (s1, rest2))] in 
    if Ascii.eqb char1 char2
      then min_helper (edit_distance (rest1, rest2)) choices
      else min_helper (S (edit_distance (rest1, rest2))) choices
  | (EmptyString, s) | (s, EmptyString) => String.length s
  end.
all: intros; simpl; rewrite Nat.add_succ_r; repeat constructor.
Qed.

Check edit_distance_equation. (* : forall ss : string * string, edit_distance ss = ... *)
Print R_edit_distance. (* Inductive R_edit_distance : string * string -> nat -> Prop := ... *)
```

The reason the graph `Inductive` definition (either then nice one you cited or the messy one generated here) doesn't require assurances of termination is that terms of `Inductive` type have to be finite already. A term of `R_edit_distance ss n` (which represents `edit_distance ss = n`) should be seen as a record or log of the steps in the computation of `edit_distance`. Though a generally recursive function could possibly get stuck in an infinite computation, the corresponding `Inductive` type excludes that infinite log: if `edit_distance ss` were to diverge, `R_edit_distance ss n` would simply be uninhabited for all `n`, so nothing blows up. In turn, you don't have the ability to actually *compute*, given `ss`, what `edit_distance ss` is or a term in `{n | R_edit_distance ss n}`, until you complete some termination proof. (E.g. proving `forall ss, {n | R_edit_distance ss n}` *is* a form of termination proof for `edit_distance`.)

Your idea to use structural recursion over some auxiliary type is exactly right (that's the *only* form of recursion that is available anyway; both `Program` and `Function` just build on it), but it doesn't really have anything to do with the graph inductive...

```
Fixpoint edit_distance
  (s1 s2 : string) (n : nat) (prf : n = String.length s1 + String.length s2)
  {struct n}
: nat := _.
```

Something along the lines of the above should work, but it'll be messy. (You *could* recurse over an instance of the graph inductive instead of the `nat` here, but, again, that just kicks the bucket to building instances of the graph inductive.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a common trick to this kind of recursion over two arguments, which is to write two nested functions, each recursing over one of the two arguments.

This can also be understood from the perspective of dynamic programming, where the edit distance is computed by traversing a matrix. More generally, the edit distance function `edit xs ys` can be viewed as a matrix of `nat` with rows indexed by `xs` and columns indexed by `ys`. The outer recursion iterates over rows `xs`, and for each of those rows, when `xs = x :: xs'`, the inner recursion iterates over its columns `ys` to generates the entries of that row from another row with a smaller index `xs'`.

```
From Coq Require Import String Ascii.
Local Open Scope string_scope.

Infix "::" := String.

(* structural recursion on xs *)
Fixpoint edit (xs ys : string) : nat :=
  match xs with
  | "" => String.length ys
  | x :: xs' =>
    (* structural recursion on ys *)
    let fix edit_xs ys :=
      match ys with
      | "" => String.length xs
      | y :: ys' =>
        let orth := min (edit xs' ys) (edit_xs ys') in
        if (x =? y)%char then
          min (edit xs' ys') orth
        else
          orth
      end in
    edit_xs ys
  end.
```